# How to send mail on windows (other than MAPI)

Tags: windows, winapi, email, mapi

When viewing the MSDN MAPI documentation page it says the API is now deprecated. If that's the case, what is the suggested API for sending mail these days?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd296734.aspx

**Edit:** Thanks for all the suggestions, the managed route isn't suitable for me as we're using MFC.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to open the message in the user's default MUA, SMAPI is your best choice.  If you want to send a message without user input, then the above suggestions are best.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know if you aren't going to use the Windows MAPI or SimpleMAPI you will have to roll your own SMTP client.

Answer (score 0):

The .NET 2.0 framework uses a mail client in the System.Net.Mail namespace.

There's a web site dedicated to it's use here:  http://www.systemnetmail.com/

Answer (score 0):

For the most part, your best bet is to use SMTP directly, in .Net 2.0+ System.Net.Mail is pretty versatile.  There are tons of other resources.  MAPI really only works if you can rely on Oulook/OE/WinMail to be setup, and in use.  You didn't specify your usage of MAPI, so u presume .Net.  Searching for an SMTP client in your prefered platform/language is your best bet.

Comment: MAPI works if you have any mail agent that supports it.  This includes Eudora as well as plenty of other mailers.

Comment: using an SMTP client to the mail server directly, as I said... there are a ton of SMTP clients available for sending email.

Answer (score 0):

just use Win32 WS api.
10 lines of code to send an email

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send a message using SMTP then you should check out Ultimate TCP/IP:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/MFC/UltimateTCPIP.aspx

It makes it very easy to send a message.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the mail client installed on the system, MAPI is still the way to go. If not, you might want a look at ChilKat, which is a COM component.